# malloc C++ VS 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, malloc

I'm trying to compile on Microsoft visual studio 2013 on C++ a  program written for linux.

the statement

```
sdesc_t *ret = _malloc(sizeof(sdesc_t));
```

return:
IntelliSense: a value of type "void *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "sdesc_t *"

any suggestion ?

Comment: Are you sure that was a C++ program?

Comment: To clarify the above, C would allow this, C++ does not.

Comment: I'm in a mix of C and C++ and as I read around the best is to convert the C part on C++. Do You think so ?

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
sdesc_t *ret = (sdesc_t *)_malloc(sizeof(sdesc_t));
```

Or better use `reinterpret_cast`:

```
sdesc_t *ret = reinterpret_cast<sdesc_t *>(_malloc(sizeof(sdesc_t)));
```

And since you are using C++, you better use `new`:

```
sdesc_t *ret = new sdesc_t;
```

And since you are using latest C++ compiler that supports `auto`, you can:

```
auto ret = new sdesc_t;
```

And since STL has rich support for smart pointers, you can simply use them. For example:

```
auto ret = std::make_unique<sdesc_t>();
```

Comment: May as well mention unique_ptr while you're at it:)

Comment: I was editing the same the moment you wrote this comment!

Answer (score 0):

Use type casting before set pointer value like

```
sdesc_t *ret = (sdesc_t *)_malloc(sizeof(sdesc_t));
```

As you written is void by default so it making error.